# A CSS3 grid list 2x6

Tags: list, css, layout, grid

I'm looking for some way to display my items list :

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

in a layout, this way:

```
_________________________
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 9 | 11| 
_________________________
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10| 12|
_________________________
```

This is for navigation / carousel purpose. As I have like 30 items to display, this template would allow to add 2 items at the beggining and remove 2 items at the end to achieve a move of all items from left to right.

This seems to be a simple layout, however I have no idea how to achived it, not breaking items sibling (of course multiple lists would do the trick, but it's ugly).
Many thanks for your support,

Jk.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the css `column-count` property. Note: The column-count property is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.

Use this css:

```
ul{
  -moz-column-count:6; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count:6; /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count:6;
}
```

With your HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `column-count` CSS property - http://jsfiddle.net/9evfz/ although this isn't supported by older browsers http://caniuse.com/#search=column-count